# Error in Android studio AVD manager and SDK manager

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I installed Android studio in my Windows 8 pc recently. Now when I try to access AVD manager or SDK manager getting an error message like "Please specify Android SDK".. What is the solution for this? 
Also is there any option in Android studio to "Close Project" like eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close the object go to File -> Close Project

Add the following in your manifest file above the  tag

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Change 8 to which minimum sdk version you want. 14 is ICS so that should be fine

Use the following for the target SDK

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

19 is Kit-Kat.

If you want to have the app on ONLY older android versions, use the following, want replace X with which API you want

```
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="X" />
```

Comment: It didn't work. When tried to run got an error from "Error configuration box " that **Cannot find any configured Android SDK**

Comment: This also **Cannot find android.app.Instrumentation class**

Comment: Start the SDK manager (3rd button from right) on the toolbar in Android studio. Make sure only API 19 is installed, not anything else. In the tools menu, only install the top 3 items

Comment: Again error getting **Please specify Android SDK** when Taking SDK manager..